# Python: handle broken unicode bytes when parsing JSON string

Tags: python, json, unicode

My code makes gets some content from an UserVoice site. As you might know, UserVoice is a shitty piece of software that can't handle data correctly; indeed, to reduce the amount of text on the search page, they cut the text at, let's say, 300 characters and then add a "..." to the end. Thing is, **they don't care cutting in the middle of a multi-bytes character**, resulting in a partial utf-8 "byte": eg. for the `è` char, I got `\xc3` instead of `\xc3\xa8s`.

Of course, when I give this horrible soup to `json.loads`, it fails with `UnicodeDecodeError`. So my question is simple: **how can I ask `json.loads` to ignore these bad bytes**, as I would do using `.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` if I had access to the internals of the function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't ask simplejson to ignore them. When I got similar problem like yours I just ran `.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode('utf-8')` and proceed.

Comment: Ok, I was currently writing an answer saying I may simply decode the string before passing it to `json.loads`. Thanks, it obviously works!

Answer (score 11):

Just pass Unicode string to `json.loads()`:

```
>>> badstr = "qualité"[:-1]+".."
>>> badstr
'qualit\xc3..'
>>> json_str = '["%s"]' % badstr
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(json_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: invalid \
continuation byte
>>> json.loads(json_str.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
[u'qualit..']
```

Comment: The answer from @Lucho includes an additional `.encode`, is it needed?

Comment: @Matteo: no. json format is defined for Unicode text and therefore `.encode()` after the `.decode()` is not necessary.